# SQL Oracle - convert row to column

Tags: sql, oracle

My SQL output currently produces this:

```
DEPARTMENT | MM-YYYY | ROW_LABEL | SCORE
   A         05-2018    STAFF      79.0
   A         06-2018    STAFF      81.0
   A         05-2018    SCHED      72.3
   A         06-2018    SCHED      74.5
   B         05-2018    STAFF      77.4
   B         06-2018    STAFF      74.3
   B         05-2018    SCHED      81.3
   B         06-2018    SCHED      78.6
```

My goal is to automatically convert the date value from the row, to be it's own column. Something like this:

```
DEPARTMENT | ROW_LABEL | 05-2018 | 06-2018
   A           STAFF      79.0      81.0
   A           SCHED      72.3      74.5
   B           STAFF      77.4      74.3
   B           SCHED      81.3      78.6
```

This report would change monthly, so the goal is that the MM-YYYY + Score are auto populated. Next time I run this it would be 06-2018 and 07-2018, I don't want to hard code the date every time I want to produce this report.

Comment: Search "Oracle Pivot"

Comment: thanks for editing that. I was trying to figure out how to produce a table like output in SO. I will look into the Pivot. My earlier google searches gave me some options but were forcing me to specifically populate my MM-YYYY column instead of taking whatever MM-YYYY was already there.

Comment: This SQL code gets me what I want today...PIVOT (SUM(SCORE) AS S FOR (MM_YYYY) IN ('05-2018' AS A, '06-2018' AS B));

But, how do I automate that IN portion so it automatically picks the MM-YYYY instead of me having to populate it? @JuanCarlosOropeza

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

**SQL DEMO**

```
SELECT 
     "DEPARTMENT", "ROW_LABEL" ,
     MAX(CASE WHEN "MMYYYY" = (select TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(sysdate,-1), 'MM-YYYY') from dual)
              THEN "SCORE"
         END) as previous_month,
     MAX(CASE WHEN "MMYYYY" = (select TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'MM-YYYY') from dual)
              THEN "SCORE"
         END) as current_month           
FROM Table1
GROUP BY "DEPARTMENT", "ROW_LABEL" 
ORDER BY "DEPARTMENT", "ROW_LABEL" DESC;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| DEPARTMENT | ROW_LABEL | PREVIOUS_MONTH | CURRENT_MONTH |
|------------|-----------|----------------|---------------|
|          A |     STAFF |             79 |            81 |
|          A |     SCHED |           72.3 |          74.5 |
|          B |     STAFF |           77.4 |          74.3 |
|          B |     SCHED |           81.3 |          78.6 |
```

If you want the exact date on the header then you need `DYNAMIC PIVOT`